# Using hasNext() and If statements

Tags: java

I NEED your help in this. I am demanded to write a java code that reads data from a file. The data in the file looks like this:

```
88 73
13 60
16 20
59
9 45
44
```

If the line has only one number (like lines 4 and 6), it represents a Fahrenheit temperature that I need to convert into Celsius. If the line has two numbers, the second number represents relative humidity. I am stuck on how to read the data line by line and one by one. I managed so far to read all the data and put them in two strings that I will later on parse into int or double, but this only works if I have two numbers per line. I know I should use if statement to read if the line has one or two numbers, but I don't know how.

Here's my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        FileInputStream file = null;
        Scanner kb = null;
        try{
            file = new FileInputStream("test2.txt");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Critical error - could not open file");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        kb = new Scanner(file);
        while (kb.hasNext()){
            String firstNum = kb.next();
            String secondNum = kb.next();
            System.out.println(firstNum);
            System.out.println(secondNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your file has one number on each line?

Comment: Some lines has two numbers and some lines has only one number. I am supposed to do calculations in the data according to that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go for a readLine and split solution

```
kb = new Scanner(file);
while (kb.hasNextLine()){
       String line = kb.nextLine();
       String arr[] = line.split (" ");
       for (String tok : arr) {
           System.out.println(tok);
       }
 }
```